# TCPDF not printing table rows containing colspan?

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am trying to print this table in TCPDF, the table is rendering fine but it is totally skipping the `<tr>` row with colspan , this happens to the only row that has the first `<td colspan="8">` cell with a colspan.

This is the html table tha:

```
<table style="font-size:7px;line-height:16px;border:none;" dir="ltr" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width:17%;"></td>
<td>YTD</td>
<td>2019</td>
<td>2018</td>
<td>2017</td>
<td>2016</td>
<td>2015</td>
<td>2014</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Portfolio</td>
<td>-3.63%</td>
<td>14.51%</td>
<td>-5.11%</td>
<td>11.16%</td>
<td>8.48%</td>
<td>-2.13%</td>
<td>2.45%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Benchmark </td>
<td>-1.64%</td>
<td>9.78%</td>
<td>-3.84%</td>
<td>7.37%</td>
<td>2.92%</td>
<td>-2.66%</td>
<td>0.08%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="8">Morningstar USD Cautious Allocation</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>
<p class="double-line">Annualised Return</p>
</td>
<td>
<p class="double-line">Standard Deviation</p>
</td>
<td>
<p class="double-line">Sharpe Ratio</p>
</td>
<td colspan="4"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Portfolio</td>
<td>4.45%</td>
<td>5.72%</td>
<td>0.78</td>
<td colspan="4"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Benchmark </td>
<td>2.08%</td>
<td>2.44%</td>
<td>0.85</td>
<td colspan="4"></td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

output on the browser page is fine (see image)

[image]

but output on the PDF removes that row completely:

[image]

Comment: strange, I use TCPDF with colspan and didn't notice that. What is your tcpdf version number ?

Comment: @Pierre thanks for your comment, I have been trying to figure this out for nearly 2 hours, the version is "6.3.2"

Comment: using 6.3.5 ; is it possible for you to update ? I will copy/paste your code in a file of mine and see what it outputs

Comment: thanks bro!! btw as you can see I have colspan on the second third  and fourth cells (annualised return, standard deviation and sharpe ratio) those are working fine, it's only not working for the first cell of a row

Comment: let me try to find 6.3.5 version

Comment: works nice with my 6.3.5 : https://file.io/70Xsrg ; if you are still having issues, we will have to dig into the tcpdf config file

Comment: great! i am testing it in 6.3.5 now

Comment: seems 6.3.5 is not making any difference for me :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210883/discussion-between-pierre-and-mikethetechy).

Comment: @Pierre finally solved it bro!! was a silly mistake of not closing the row `</tr>` , cuz the browser and wordpress WYSSIG editor adds auto closing tag the whole time I have not been able to understand why. luckily after checking the HTML directly on the DB. things cleared up!! thank you so much for being there and confirming it's not an issue with `TCPDF`. see my answer below for details :)

Comment: NICE ! Pretty hard to find this missing `</tr>` as you explained... Glad you solved it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is solved, the problem was not in TCPDF, It was the table not having a proper closing tag for the row `</tr>` . The table above was coming from a `custom field` storing it in the DB of a wordpress site. Since the html is generated through a php code I had minor coding error that I forgot to close the row with `</tr>`. However when viewing the html content in a wordpress WYSWIG editor , it adds the self closing tags. When you debugging it on the browser page also most browsers add auto closing tags. These made me think that the html structure of the table is good and should be an issue with `TCPDF`. After checking the HTML in the database I finally figured out the table row wasn't closing properly.

[image]

[image]
Hopefully this will help someone having a similar issue in the future.